# Question about unique subfields in cyclotomic fields.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I'm self-studying Number Theory and searching for exercises for number theory I came across this [assignment](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Erse/205a.1.13f/205A_Problems.pdf) which has this exercise:

(Special Cyclotomic Case). Let $p$ be an odd prime, $\omega=\omega_{p}$
a primitive $p$th root of unity. Show all of the following:

1. If $d\mid p-1$, then there exists a unique subfield $F_{d}$ of $\mathbb{Q}\left(\omega\right)$
   of degree $d$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, e.g., $F_{2}=\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{\left(-1\right)^{\frac{p-1}{2}}}p\right)$.
2. $F_{d_{1}}\subseteq F_{d_{2}}$ if and only if $d_{1}\mid d_{2}$.
3. If $q\neq p$ is an odd prime and $d\mid p-1$, then $q$ is a $d$th
   power modulo $p$ if and only if $q$ splits completely in $F_{d}$.
4. (Quadratic Reciprocity) If $p$ and $q$ are two odd primes, then
   the Legendre symbol $\left(\dfrac{p}{q}\right)=1$ if and only if
   $q$ splits completely in $F_{2}$ if and only if the Legendre Symbol
   $\left(\dfrac{d_{\mathbb{Q}\left(\omega\right)}}{q}\right)=1$. In
   particular,
   $$\left(\dfrac{q}{p}\right)\left(\dfrac{p}{q}\right)=\left(-1\right)^{\frac{p-1}{2}\frac{q-1}{2}}.$$

I'm struggling currently to prove the second question which is needed to show the third one (I suppose). I have no clue how to relate the degree with the unique subfields of $\mathbb{Q}\left(\omega\right)$. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: How did you solve the first one? I suppose you used Galois correspondence? And just to be sure do you actually mean $F_{d_1}\subseteq F_{d_2}$?

Comment: @Lxm I used (in general terms) that because $F_{2}$ has to be a quadratic field then it has to be of the form $\mathbb{Q}\left(\sqrt{d}\right)$ with $d$ free of squares. If $q$ is a prime that divides $p$ if $q$ ramifies $F_{2}$ then has to ramify $\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_{p}\right)$ So if $d\mid q$ with $q$ a prime, then $q$ does not ramify $F_{2}$. So $q$ has to be $p$, and then because $p$ is prime, then it has to be $-1$ or $\pm p$. But $-1$ cannot be the one because $i\notin\mathbb{Q}\left(\zeta_{p}\right)$. (Maybe I'm not in the correct path with this one too)

Comment: And yes, I mean $\subseteq$ sorry.

Comment: Do you know that Gal$(\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p),\mathbb{Q})\simeq(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$, the multiplicative group of the field with $p$ elements, which is a cyclic group? Subgroup of some fixed index (equivalently of fixed order) of a cyclic group is unique (if exists). Then you can use the Galois correspondence between intermediate fields and subgroups of the Galois group. I believe this does not have that much to do with 3 or 4 though.

Comment: @Lxm yes, I am aware of that but I don't know how to relate that if a given unique subfield is contained in another one, then its order has to divide the other one and viceversa. I haven't seen anywhere a relation of divisibility in this conditions. Maybe it has to do with the properties of subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^*$

Comment: Yes. Basically the subgroups of a cyclic group are very concrete; if the cyclic group is generated by $a$ then a subgroup must be generated by $a^n$ for some $n$, and you can try to guess the relation between two subgroups in terms of different $n$. If you want a reference, the setup of this exercise looks quite similar to the proof in chapter 4 Marcus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Galois theory, the sub-field structure of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$ (where $\omega_p = e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p}}$) corresponds with the subgroup structure of $Aut(\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p))$, the automorphism group of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$.


Clearly, when $\sigma \in Aut(\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p))$, then $\left(\sigma(\omega_p)\right)^p = \sigma(\omega_p^p) = \sigma(1) = 1$, so $\sigma(\omega_p)$ is again a $p-th$ order root of unity, hence we must have $\sigma(\omega_p) = \omega_p^j$ for some $j \in \{1,2,...,p-1\}$.
Also, defining $\sigma_j$ by $\sigma_j(\omega_p) = \omega_p^j$, we see that $\sigma_j\left(\sigma_k(\omega_p)\right) = \sigma_j(\omega_p^k) = \omega_p^{jk}$, implying that $Aut(\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p))$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_p^*$, so it is cyclic, generated by $\sigma_g$ where $g$ is a generator of $\mathbb{F}_p^*$.


The subgroups of a cyclic group $<\negthickspace \sigma \negthickspace>$ are $<\negthickspace\sigma^e\negthickspace>$ where $e$ divides the group order, $p-1$ in this case. Thus, for example, for $p=13$ we get the following correspondence between subfields of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_p)$ and subgroups of $\mathbb{F}_p^*$:

[image]

Where $p^*=\left(\frac{-1}{p}\right) p$, in the example $p^*= 13$.

This answers (1) and (2).
I leave (3) and (4) for you :-).